# How can I use Bluetooth to have a two player game set up on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

I want (in my game) to have a mode where two people can be on two different iPhones and play with each other via a Bluetooth connection... How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple's GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) will do that for you easily. Your code will work over Bluetooth and WLAN.